# Change MAC address for TEW-444UB wifi USB connector?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, mac-address

The free wifi networks in the public libraries where I live only allow 2h/day share. They use the MAC address to check if a user has used up his daily quota.

To bypass this limitation, I'd like to change the USB connector's MAC address. Does someone know if a utility is available for XP and this device?

Thank you.

Comment: I applaud your honesty, but you might get more sympathy if you don't tell people *why* you want to do it in this particular situation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some instructions here

[Changing the MAC address in W2K and XP](http://www.nthelp.com/NT6/change_mac_w2k.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable in the registry and making the changes yourself, you can use applications like [MadMACs](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/madmacs-mac-spoofer) to do it for you. This one even includes a randomizing feature so you don't have to enter a new one yourself each time.